# gstreamer-vaapi pipeline, why it is not working and how to fix it?

Tags: video, gstreamer, glib

I'm experimenting with gstreamer and I find this as working:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/path/to/file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapisink
```

I want to be able to output video to my window, I've tried this but without any success

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/path/to/file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapidownload | appsink
```

this example is trivial as I'm still learning gstreamer, so my idea is to provide my own opengl texture for gstreamer to play vaapi-decoded video. Any tips for that will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT :**

gst-inspect of:

**vaapidecode** : http://pastebin.com/8TSJF7jN

**vaapidownload** : http://pastebin.com/JzV17v33

**vaapisink** : http://pastebin.com/ZkMBVh8v

**appsink** : http://pastebin.com/ehkQsraM

This is output from second pipeline: http://pastebin.com/9mqjsLUq

**UPDATE:**

Same output, but with log level 3: http://pastebin.com/GRGTVYVm

Comment: You need to be mindful of which plugins can plug into other plugins. I'm guessing there's a mismatch in formats. Study the src and sink formats of the components in play. What kind of data does vaapidecode output? What does vaapidownload consume and produce? You can find out using 'gst-inspect'. Also, edit the post so that it states the specific error you get with the second line.

Comment: Thanks for tips, please accept my excuses for bad question. I've edited the question so it describes problem more precisely.

Comment: VA API is a library that sits on top of various other video acceleration APIs. From the output you posted, it looks like you are using XvBA, ATI/AMD's acceleration API. Do you know if this is working separately from GStreamer? Do you have a basic XvBA app that can validate that functionality?

Comment: Oh, sure, I can play file with vaapi with vlc or mplayer and use if with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that vaapidownload needs fix, take a look https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672106

A fix should be here http://gitorious.org/~hkaelber/vaapi/hkaelbers-gstreamer-vaapi/commit/60b1781c7de58df7e87bb471a0fdb286f7451dcf

Answer (score 0):

The formats are fine. Otherwise it would result in a not-negotiated or dataflow error. I suspect that for some reason the surface is not "downloadable". If you run GST_DEBUG="*:3" gst-launch .... or higher, does the log give more info?

Comment: No, I get same log. Could that be a bug in element vaapidownload?

Comment: If you run GST_DEBUG="*:3" gst-launch ... you should get quite a bit of output. If not your gstreamer installation has the debug logging disabled which is uncommon - what distribution are you on?
Also the error indicates that vaapidownload is unhappy with something, hence the suggestion to dive into the log. Once we ensured the logging works, we need to figure the name of the log category of the vaapi elements and then you can do e.g. GST_DEBUG="*:3,*vaapi*:5" gst-launch 2>debug.log ...

Comment: The trick was in GST_DEBUG="*:3", here is the output http://pastebin.com/GRGTVYVm (I hope that you can see it nicely with colors). I've noticed warning that says vaapidownload gstvaapidownload.c:418:gst_vaapidownload_transform: failed to download NV12 image from surface 0x03000000 at 0:00:00.159995990

Comment: Okay, now you could raise the log level for that category: GST_DEBUG="\*:2,\*vaapi\*:5" gst-launch 2>debug.log ...
Use GST_DEBUG_NO_COLOR=1 in addition to strip the colors.

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/pDMZb9HC. Check my answer, that could be the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you posted for the second command line, it looks like the command is working. vaapidecode decodes the video to an x-surface, vaapidownload takes the x-surface and outputs x-raw-yuv, and appsink consumes absolutely *anything* without producing anything else (so it appears to be doing nothing). Try muxing the raw YUV into a YUV4MPEG (.y4m) file:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/path/to/file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapidownload | y4menc ! filesink location=decoded-video.y4m
```

See if that command produces a .y4m file and then watch that video using VLC or MPlayer or ffplay to verify correctness.

Comment: I used 

gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=video.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapidownload ! y4menc ! filesink location=test.yuv

and result was 0 kB size test.yuv file, error was same as before

Comment: Thanks for correcting my command (missed the filesink). Sorry I can't be of more help right now.

Comment: According to the log vaapidownload outputs NV12 raw yuv video, but y4menc only accepts IYUV, I420, Y42B, Y41B, or Y444.

Try: ... ! vaapidownload ! ffmpegcolorspace ! y4menc ! filesink locataion=foo.y4m

Comment: I've tried that but I got same output as one from second pipeline. Same as if after vaapidownload I put autovideosink that should work with anything. For me, it looks like vaapidownload is not working as it should.